# Server providing real time game status updates

Tags: java, networking, client-server

Currently my game server is small (one area and ~50 AI) and each time it sends out state update packets (UDP), it sends out a complete state to each client. This creates a packet size of ~1100 bytes. Pretty much all it sends is the following information for all entities:

```
int uid
int avatarImage
float xPos
float yPos
int direction
int attackState
24 bytes
```

**Edit: More efficient structure**

```
int uid
byte avatarImage
float xPos
float yPos
byte direction & attackState
14 bytes
```

but I am going to need to send more information eventually for the entities. For instance I am adding to this:

```
float targetXPos
float targetYPos
float speed
```

As more data is needed to be sent for each entity, I am fast approaching and most likely already passed the maximum size of the packet. So I am trying to think of a few possible ways to fix my problem:

1) Just build up the status update packet until I run out of room and then leave out the rest. Very bad client view. Not really an option.

2) Only send the data for the N closest entities to a client. This requires that each state update I calculate the closest N for each client. This could be very time consuming.

3) Some how design the packets so that I can send multiple for the same update. Currently, the client assumes the packets are in the following structure:

```
int currentMessageIndex
int numberOfPCs
N * PC Entity data
int numberOfNPCs
N * NPS Entity data
```

The client then takes this new data and completely overwrites its copy of the state. Since the packets are complete self contained, even if the client miss a packet, it will be ok. I am not sure how I will implement the idea of multiple packets for the same update, because if I miss one of them, what then? I can't overwrite the complete, outdated state with a update, partial state.

4) Only send the actual variables that change. For instance, for each entity I add one int that is a bit mask for each field. Things such as speed, target, direction, and avatarImage won't need to be sent every update. I still come back to the issue of what happens if the client misses a packet that did actually need to update one of these values. I am not sure how critical this would be. This also requires a little more computation on both the client and server side for creating/reading the packet, but not too much.

Any better ideas out there?

Comment: I like number 4 idea you have.  However, if the any of the information is connected to each other (like speed and direction).  Make sure those are sent together. If the client misses a packet in either case....it still will miss the update...whether the data is sent all at once or only when it changes.

Comment: what about compression? or some sort of custom encoding? if you know beforehand the ranges of some of the values, you can afford to lose some bits on each field...

Comment: I like number 4, too. In addition to sending the *update* packets, you may send the *whole_status* packets on request of the client. And when you include a serial number into the *update* packets, the client knows when it should request a *whole_status*.

Comment: So you guys don't have any additional ideas? I like 4 as well, but if there are enough entities and enough of them have changed a lot, then much of this data will all be sent, and could possibly overflow the packet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with number 4 and number 2. 
As you have realized, it is usually better to only send updates instead of a complete game state. But make sure you always send absolute values and not deltas, so that no information is lost should a packet be dropped. You can use dead reckoning on the client side to make animations as smooth as possible under crappy networking conditions.
You have to design carefully for this so that it is not critical if a packet is lost.

As for number 2, it does not has to be time consuming if you design for it. For example, you can have your game area divided into a grid of squares where each entity is always in exactly one particular square and let the game world keep track on this. In that case, calculating the entities in the 9 surronding grids is a O(1) operation.

Comment: This isn't a grid coordinate system, as you can see by float xPos, yPos. There are no grids, and I allow PCs to overlap, so you could have 50 people right on top of each other.

Answer (score 1):

This type of system is commonly solved using a [Dead Reckoning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_reckoning) or [predictive contract](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3230/dead_reckoning_latency_hiding_for_.php) algorithm.  You can't depend on all clients getting updates at the same time, so you need to predict positions based on previously known values and then validate these predictions against server-generated results.

Comment: I already know that, but the problem is still how to get all the data to the client so that it can use that to do Dead Rechoning. It can't do it with out some kind of speed and direction, or in this case a target it is pathing to.

Comment: You won't be able to guarantee each client gets updated at the same time; thus the dead reckoning. Your server should be the authoritative source for entity position; but each client can predict where it and all other entities are going based on the data you've already provided - position, direction, speed, and target. Every x ms, your server should send out the latest position deltas, which your clients will use to correct their predictions.  The packet for this can simply be { uid, deltax, deltay }.  You'll seen separate packets for speed, direction, and target changes.

Comment: You're wasting bits in your original packet structure.  You probably don't have INT_MAX avatar images or attack states. You can reduce these by using a bitmask instead of ints. You may be able to do the same with your uid and direction as well.

Comment: You are correct about my current packet structure. I will update it to be what I see as the most efficient, and still does what I need.

Answer (score 0):

One problem I ran into sending delta updates (basically your 4th option), is that the data can be out of order or just old, depending on how concurrent your server is, basically race conditions of multiple clients updating the server at the same time.

My solution was to send an update notification to all the clients, with a bitmask setting a bit for each item that has been updated.

Then the client requests the current value of the specific data based on the bitmask, This also allows the client to only request data it is interested in.

The advantage of this is it avoids race conditions and the client always gets the latest value.

The disadvantage is it requires a roundtrip to get the actual value.

UPDATE to demonstrate the point I am trying to make.

Presume 4 clients A,B,C,D.
A and B send simultaneous updates to a mutable state X on the server Xa and Xb. As B gets in somewhat later than A the final state of X on the server is X= Xb.

The server sends out the updated status as it gets it to all clients, so C and D get the updated status of X, as the order of delivery is indeterminant C gets Xa then Xb and D gets Xb then Xa, so at this point the clients C and D have different ideas of the state of X, one reflects what the server has the other doesn't, it has deprecated (or old) data.

On the other hand if the server just sends out a notification that X has changed to all the clients, C and D will get two status change notifications for X. They both make requests for the current state of X, and they both end up with the final state of X on the server which is Xb.

As the order of the status notification is irrelevant as there is no data in it, and the clients issue a request for the updated state on each notification they both end up with consistent data,

I hope that is more clear as to the point I was trying to make.

Yes it does increase the latency, but the designer has to decide what is more important, the latency or having all clients reflecting the same state of mutable data. This will depend on the data and the game.

Comment: Client data is always old, so forcing the client to request it doesn't solve that. The only real issue is how old. If the server is correctly managing the world state then it should be able to send out updates to any interested clients without problems.

Comment: Old meaning deprecated. If multiple clients update the same data at the same time there is no way to guarantee one client doesn't get out-of-date data. Concurrency means messages are received in a non-deterministic order. My method means you always get the latest that the server knows about and never get the wrong data, although it may have to do two requests back to back. Think about it, it is complicated.

Comment: In the context of real time updates you should be sending changed state to interested clients right when it changes. It's a classic observer pattern over the network. Then there is no need for a roundtrip to get the latest value as you either already have it or it is on its way to you. Either way you always have to assume that you might have old data because information takes time to travel from the server to the client and the data may have changed again since the last notification. An extra round-trip just means you get old data that is a bit less old.

Comment: @kylotan I'm sorry I am not being clear, I am not talking about how old the data is, obviously it is going to have latency. I am pointing out a somewhat hard to grasp concept of concurrent updates of mutable data. I'll update my answer to demonstrate what I am talking about.

Comment: "as the order of delivery is indeterminant" - ah, so you're concerned about reordering of data. Given that UDP is being used the data may not arrive at all! So you would assume the client is robust to this. As for re-requesting the data, I don't see it makes a difference - either way you get a value that was definitely correct at some point in the past, and it can always differ across clients due to them receiving their responses at different times. Perfect synchronisation of state across multiple clients and the server requires locking that state otherwise you're always at the mercy of time.

Comment: @kylotan I am sorry I cannot express what I am trying to say here in a way it is understandable. This is not simply a reordering of data issue, and no amount of locking in the server can help on the client side if you think about it. Getting inconsistent state data on clients can be bad in many situations, and I am presenting a way to avoid it, it works I have used it for years.